# callback race: button click to trigger ajax, whose callback won't execute on time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, callback, race-condition

I have what I think is a fairly classical problem involving what looks to me like a callback race, but in spite of all my reading, I'm still stuck. You'll find the code pasted below.

It's a simple log in form and you can see that when a certain button is clicked, I'll send the form data "ajaxically" to an external php file. Once the php has run, I'm to receive the results back, and as a test here, to simply alert out the email address from the php file.

When I run this, the ajax callback doesn't execute. If I click the button fast and repeatedly, I get the right alert. I also get the right response if I put in an extra alert.

How do I get it to run without doing these other silly things?

Thanks in advance
RR

```
  $('#'+this.loginForm[0].parentId+"logIn")
      .on('click', function() {
        var jax = $.ajax(
          {  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "../sharedfunctions3/act-membership.php",
          data: {email: document.getElementById(that.parentId+'email').value, 
                  password: document.getElementById(that.parentId+'password').value,
                  path: that.path,
                  action: "logIn"
                }
          });

        jax.done(function() 
              { 
              obj = JSON.parse($.trim(jax.responseText)); 
              alert(obj.email);
              });
        jax.fail(function() { alert("error"); });
      alert(1);
      });
```

Comment: in your click callback, end it with `return false;`

Comment: oh! was that all! wonderful, it works, many thanks @MarshallHouse ;

Comment: I'd like also to understand why that works: Is it because "return  false" signals that the callback has come to an end, and that the compiler can go ahead with the "done/fail" check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a hunch that when you clicked the button the browser was submitting synchronously and asynchronously.

The `return false;` tells the browser to not submit the form and to prevent default actions from there on.

When a button inside of a form tag is clicked, most browsers will submit the form even though it is not a submit input.